# RegExp How to check text is match with ALL of wordkeys or match any two of keys

Tags: regex

I wish to test string match with some conditions

Condition: All keys must be present.

RegExp: `^(?=.*key1)(?=.*key3)(?=.*key2)`

Text: `rer key1 werjk key2 and key2 and key3 and end`

Text matched!

And now my questions:

- How can I test string to match any two keys out of three?
- How can I test string to match any one key out of three?

Comment: Do you mean "two or more" or "exactly two, but not three"?

Comment: Exactly two, not count duplicate keys

Comment: So your example text should fail in both cases but succeed on `rer key1 werjk key2 and key2`?

Comment: Yes,and match for "teh dsfe key1 and then key3"

Comment: I hope you realize that using something like `String.indexOf(string, fragment)` in java or something similar in other programming languages has better performance and will produce simpler code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not trivial to solve in a single regex. Well, it *is*  trivial for the simple examples you showed, but it won't scale because you need to do the possible permutations yourself.

Two out of three (written in verbose mode for "readability":

```
^
(?:
 (?=.*key1)(?=.*key2)(?!.*key3)
 |
 (?=.*key1)(?=.*key3)(?!.*key2)
 |
 (?=.*key3)(?=.*key2)(?!.*key1)
)
```

One out of three:

```
^
(?:
 (?=.*key1)(?!.*key2)(?!.*key3)
 |
 (?=.*key2)(?!.*key1)(?!.*key3)
 |
 (?=.*key3)(?!.*key2)(?!.*key1)
)
```

Comment: Great (if you have to use a regex). If not, I'd strongly advise you to use @dbaupp's solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the keys are plain strings, then this is a situation where not using regexes is probably more efficient and clearer. e.g. in Python (using the fact that `True == 1` and `False == 0`):

```
def matchExactlyN(text, keys, n):
   return sum(key in text for key in keys) == n
```

```
>>> text = "rer key1 werjk" 
>>> matchExactlyN(text, ["key1","key2","key3"], 1) # 1 of 3
True
>>> matchExactlyN(text, ["key1","key2","key3"], 2) # 2 of 3
False
```

Comment: +1, although I'd use `key in text` instead of `text.find(key) != -1`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, oh, yeah; that's much nicer :)